# Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate File Not Found Error, but still working

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm running SSL Certificates from [Let's Encrypt](http://letsencrypt.org). I've got them installed on my Ubuntu machine running Apache. The setup works fine and I can launch the website, see the green padlock and even got an A+ on SSL Labs.

The problem is that when I do **apachectl configtest** the server would return a file not found error:

```
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem' not exist or is empty.
```

But `sudo service apache2 restart` works just fine.

I got this question running at [Let's Encrypt Community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apache-sslcertificatefile-error-does-not-exist-or-is-empty/14995) but the issue hasn't been resolved yet.

`sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem` works, returns valid certificate details.

```
sudo x509 -text -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
```

does not work and returns the error below:

```
Error opening Certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
139774254929568:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem.','r')
139774254929568:error:2007402:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
ubable to load certificate
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting errors on **apachectl configtest** and **openssl**?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Almost certainly some permission or other error preventing apache from reading the file

Comment: Yep, likely permissions, like @DerfK said.

Comment: @DerfK I'm thinking the same. **/etc/letsencrypt/live** is owned by **root** with **0700** permission. I tried changing it to **0755** but I continue to get the same error. Everything else inside that directory is 0755 already,, still owned by root.

Comment: @jarvis in that case it might be SELinux related. Check its audit log and see `audit2allow`

Comment: Same here. Permissions for `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` **and** `/etc/letsencrypt/live` needed to be manually set to 0755

Comment: This problem drove me crazy for a while, until I realized it was a much simpler issue than I thought... see my answer below https://serverfault.com/a/887247/300817

Comment: If you deleted another Certificate with `sudo certbot delete`, after that you must manually delete the file and symbolic link: File: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<domain>-le-ssl.conf` and symbolic link: ` /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<domain>-le-ssl.conf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several sleepless nights, I finally got it to work. *(overkill statement)* We all know it was permissions, but exactly where was something to check.

I kept on working with **/ect/letsencrypt/live** and the directories and files under that. I kept changing permissions from the original to 0755 and 0777. What I did not immediately see was that **/etc/letsencrypt/live** *was a link created from* /etc/letsencrypt/archive and it had a **0700** permission. That's why it wasn't able to read the file. After changing the permission of **/etc/letsencrypt/archive** to **0755**, `apachectl configtest` already responded with `Syntax OK`.

Although the original issue was resolved, I will refer this back to [Let's Encrypt](http://letsencrypt.org) because this was all Auto Installation of Certificates. Something like this should not happen in "auto". But my setup might have something to do with the permission issue since I installed it using a non-root user (but I did sudo).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the same issue in ``apachectl configtest``.

The file exists, the ``sudo openssl ...`` outputs all right.

Tried to set permissions ``sudo chmod -R 0755 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/`` and the problem persists...

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this same issue, I did restart, it 'errored' but actually restarted ok. I simply changed the /live directory permissions and it started working again.

Comment: Have just come across this, whilst the answer is correct, I think with the updates letsencrypt have done recently changing permissions on archive doesn't work. Doing so directly on the live folder does now however. `sudo chmod -R 0755 /etc/letsencrypt/live`

Comment: I had the same error yet permissions did not solve it for me. I had a working setup that completely broke down after restarting the server. After the restart, it turned out that the linked .pem files were linking to files that did not exist at all. More details here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ssl-certificate-does-not-exist-or-is-empty-alternative-root-cause-and-solution/33343

Comment: Simply running the config test as sudo is sufficient.   There is no need to change the folder permissions.

Comment: Could changing permissions at this level be a security breach?

Answer (score 23):

In my case the files and permissions where not the issue. I was trying to restart the server with `apachectl restart` or test the config (`apachectl -t` or `apachectl configtest`). The user running the command (me) simply didn't have the proper permissions to access the certificates. I just had to prefix the commands with `sudo` to run them as root! No more errors, the config test returns "Syntax OK" and I can restart the server. (OK I'm a bit embarrassed it took me so long to figure that one out...)

Comment: This isn't the issue on Debian machines it seems, but it was the issue on my fedora server. Thanks for saving me many hours.

Comment: Jokes, it happened on my ubuntu machine too... like a year later...

Comment: yup apachectl command not found until sudo prefaced it. thanks @mrtnmgs

Comment: If you deleted another Certificate with `sudo certbot delete`, after that you must manually delete the file and symbolic link: File: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<domain>-le-ssl.conf` and symbolic link: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<domain>-le-ssl.conf`. That was my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Agreeing with [timeSmith's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/868018/518682) that the permissions on these files and folders are intentionally tight, and should be left as `0700`.

You need to run `service httpd` or `apachectl` commands as `sudo` so that these processes have root privileges and get read access to the letsencrypt certificate folders and files.

Answer (score 2):

As originally commented by [Ian Terle](https://serverfault.com/users/370535/ian-tearle), changing the permissions on the "live" directory now fixes the issue:

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 /etc/letsencrypt/live
```

Note: I was observing the same error as the OP.

This was confirmed on:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Seeing downvotes, so I suspect this was probably related to a bug of some variety. Please comment if this is now fixed/patched/deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The permissions on the cert files are best left very tight. To allow the appropriate processes access to the cert files: start apache using the following commands.

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Alternately restart gracefully using this command:

```
sudo service httpd graceful
```

Comment: I am not sure it is necessary to start apache with sudo.  Certificates seem to work without doing so.

Comment: Running any kind of web server as sudo is a very dangerous practice.

Comment: Yes, if [semtex41's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/773440/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-file-not-found-error-but-still-working/847265#847265) works then definitely do that.