# Can't Start HTTPD After Update

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, lets-encrypt

I'm unable to start my previously working `httpd`(2.4.6) after updating my instance(CentOS 7).

I first checked the status via `systemctl status httpd`, which yielded:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-12-05 09:05:37 CET; 6s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 8033 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8032 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8032 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps kill[8033]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 05 09:05:37 vps systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Not really helpful, there isn't a specific error message to point me somewhere. Therefore I did a `apachectl configtest` which showed a problem with a Let's Encrypt certificate file not being where it should be or being empty. The same problem is also mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/773440/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-file-not-found-error-but-still-working).

It's weird because as in the issue I pointed to above, the certificate exists and `openssl` can work it.

As the suggestion from the above issue, I recursively changed the permissions of `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live` to 0755.

Now `apachectl configtest` does not complain about anything and outputs the syntax as ok.

However, my `httpd` still does not start with exact same `systemctl` message as above.

What am I missing here?

p.s. I also checked for any other `httpd` processes out in the system to kill them; there weren't any and nothing else is on port 80.

### Update

My Apache error log:

```
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.247181 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 866] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.249196 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 866] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.252624 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 866] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.257286 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 866] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.288880 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 866] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 25 03:37:10.288906 2018] [core:notice] [pid 866] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Dec 02 03:46:09.992864 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 866] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

Comment: Does apache logs says something? May be change loglevel in apache config to info or even debug is a good idea.

Comment: There should be a pretty clear error message in the apache error log.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

It seems there was a problem with my error/request logs I used for my available sites.

It wasn't properly guiding me there through Apache's own status messages(in reality, Apache was a bit cryptic through `systemctl status httpd` or `journalctl -xe`) but with the comments above, I was able to track it down there and once I:

- deleted all my past log files(they were really messy),
- properly named them in the configuration files(choose a universal naming schema and stick to it),
- created these ones with the given names above,

Apache was able to restart.

I assume a breakout happened because when I updated my system, Apache had to restart and it read the new configuration files which were broken.